# How to name ops and tensor creation in TF2 to help logging/debugging?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm using Tensorflow 2.0a and `tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)` to log the placement of each ops. But some of the ops are quite cryptic.. it is important for me to understand what those ops correspond to because they run on the CPU and might slow down my training.

In particular: `VarIsInitializedOp, AssignVariableOp, ReadVariableOp`

Is there a clear mapping of those ops to a particular **tf** call I could flag in my code?

```
Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2019-05-30 16:20:56.082274: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:394] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Executing op VarIsInitializedOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2019-05-30 16:20:56.082418: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:394] Executing op VarIsInitializedOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2019-05-30 16:20:56.084034: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:394] Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Executing op ReadVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2019-05-30 16:20:56.258670: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:394] Executing op ReadVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
```